# Stress testing an RDS server / farm

Tags: terminal-server, stress-testing, rds

I need to find a way to autotest a small RDS deployment for ~50 users, working in a set of RDS session hosts. 
The users are going to be mainly running MS Office 2007 - Excel, Word, Outlook (connected to Exchange 2010)

Is there a known set of scripts or software I can freely use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's Remote Desktop Services Resource Kit ([Amazon link for book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735627371)) comes with a set of scripts and tools that will allow you to do automated load testing on an RDS setup.  It's not exactly push-button, but all the tools you need are provided.  This stuff may well be available for free elsewhere...I got it with the book.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, so I'd need to purchase the book to get the tools?

Comment: Not sure, these resources may be freely available elsewhere....but I got them with the book.